# How can I fix damaged interlocking weatherstripping?

Tags: door-frame, weatherstripping

Our front door has interlocking metal weatherstripping.  It looks to me like it was bent on the bottom, seemingly because a bottom weather strip was installed in a way to bend the metal rim when the door closed.  But I am not sure, as the bent metal does almost look like it was installed this way (even though it doesn’t allow the door to seal).  Is this ever normal or can I bend it back and cut back the bottom stripping?

Weather stripping installed over metal interlocking stripping:
[image: Weather stripping installed over metal interlocking stripping]

Possibly damaged interlocking stripping on door jamb:
[image: Possibly damaged interlocking stripping on door jamb]

Stripping on hinge side also bent:
[image: Stripping on hinge side also bent]

Comment: I cant see what you can see.  That curved bit just looks to me like a deflector for rain, perhaps with a strip or brush under it.  If thats not true, then we need better photos.

Comment: Are you talking about the bottom of the door?  I'm talking about the door jamb, where the slotted metal weatherstripping looks bent on the bottom 2-3 inches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sweep looks like an add-on to me. You're correct that it's the problem.

1. Take the sweep off and trim it back to clear the side weather stipping. A miter saw or hack saw would do well.
2. Place cardboard or similar behind the bent part (to protect the jamb) and gently tap it back into shape with a hammer and wood block.

Comment: This is along what I was thinking (especially since the bent metal prevents that door from sealing on the bottom), but what gives me pause is that the stripping is also bent on the door jamb side -- and bent in a way that is NOT due to the sweep.  It's a bit hard to see in the photo.  It makes me think the stripping was pre-bent. 
Does interlocking weatherstripping ever come already bent that way?

Comment: I don't think so. The other side may just be incidental damage.